# Ubuntu 16.04 64bit unable to install vim, libsqlite3-dev

Tags: ubuntu, vim, installation, dependencies, package

I've trying to install vim and libsqlite3-dev but I always keep on getting a message that **some packages could not be installed** and I cannot find a way to fix it. I've tried the following commands but still no lick.

```
apt-get upgrade
apt-get update
apt-get update --fix-missing
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**Installing Vim**

```
:~# apt-get install vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vim : Depends: vim-common (= 2:7.4.963-1ubuntu4) but 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When trying a command vim it shows

```
:~# vim
The program 'vim' can be found in the following packages:
 * vim
 * vim-gnome
 * vim-tiny
 * vim-athena
 * vim-athena-py2
 * vim-gnome-py2
 * vim-gtk
 * vim-gtk-py2
 * vim-gtk3
 * vim-gtk3-py2
 * vim-nox
 * vim-nox-py2
```

**Installing libsqlite3-dev**

```
:~# apt-get install -y libsqlite3-dev ruby2.3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsqlite3-dev : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.10.2-1) but 3.11.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Better [ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue was fixed after I made a **distribution upgrade** then restart my computer. After that I was able to install vim etc.